# Delete values over the diagonal in a matrix with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the next problem with a matrix in python and numpy

given this matrix

```
     Cmpd1  Cmpd2   Cmpd3   Cmpd4
Cmpd1   1   0.32    0.77    0.45
Cmpd2   0.32    1   0.14    0.73
Cmpd3   0.77    0.14    1   0.29
Cmpd4   0.45    0.73    0.29    1
```

i want to obtain this:

```
    Cmpd1   Cmpd2   Cmpd3   Cmpd4
Cmpd1   1           
Cmpd2   0.32    1       
Cmpd3   0.77    0.14    1   
Cmpd4   0.45    0.73    0.29    1
```

I was trying with np.diag() but doesnt works

Thanks!

Comment: What did you actually try and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.tril(a)` to extract the lower triangular matrix. 
Refer this : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you convert your matrix to a numpy matrix first, then, if you want to extract the lower part of the matrix, use:

```
np.tril(a)
```

where 'a' is your matrix. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html#numpy.tril

Equally, if you need the upper part of the matrix, use:

```
np.triu(a)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html